# Why can't I select the "stereo mix" as my recording source? (Windows XP SP3)

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, audio-recording

I'm on Windows XP SP3 and have a SigmaTel audio driver installed.  For some reason, there is no option to select "stereo mix" as a recording source - the source doesn't have a channel, fader, or mute option (checkbox).  The "stereo mix" option is also missing from the properties window.  Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is and/or how to fix/bypass it?  This is the first time I've had this happen to me.  The limited options of the application feel old and obsolete.  Maybe all I need is an updated driver, but I tried to find everything I could for both SigaTel and AC97.

I also tried using a Realtek A97 driver for the hell of it and still couldnt figure out how to enable and record from the stereo mix.

Anyone have any ideas?

Here's what it should look like:
[image]

And here's what mine looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try these: *Start -> Control Panel -> Sounds And Devices ->
Audio* tab. Under *Sound recording* click *Volume* button, unmute *Stereo Mix*

If you don't see *Stereo Mix* there, then go *Options -> Properties*, select *Stereo Mix* and click OK.

Comment: this would absolutely work, but i realize i need to modify the question because there option isn't even there to be checked on or off